# Cannot get z-index to work in my table

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML table with an object element and a span tag inside one td parent tag like so:

HTML:

```
<table class="tableClass">
<tr>
<td class="tdClass"><object data="http://mydata.com"></object><span>My Text</span></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Now the table has a background color of #999. Basically, with z-indexing, I want the  element to hide behind the  element, but the span element should be on top of the #999 table background. How do I achieve this?

My CSS:

```
.tableClass{
  background: #999;
}
.tdClass object{
  z-index:999;
}

.tdClass span{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1; (if I make it -1, it disappears behind the table background...)
}
```

Currently the span element with the text is on top of the object element...I want it behind the object element and infront of the table background.

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.tdClass object` needs at least `position:relative`, as `z-index` will only work on block-level elements which aren't `position:static`. Try the following:

```
.tableClass{
  background: #999;
}
.tdClass object{
  position:relative;
  z-index:999;
}

.tdClass span{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

See also [CSS2.1: 9.9.1 Specifying the stack level: the 'z-index' property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#z-index):

> For a **positioned box**, the 'z-index' property specifies:
>
> 1. The stack level of the box in the current stacking context.
> 2. Whether the box establishes a stacking context.

Comment: thank you, it works. But I don't understand your logic: "as z-index will only work on block-level elements which aren't position:relative". But if the object element has a position: relative, why does it have the z-index specified then?

Comment: @DexterSchneider: Oops, I meant `position:static`, which is the default value.